# AngularJS : filter and bold part of the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, angularjs

I have a list filtered like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query | limitTo:10"
```

and a search input

```
ng-model="search.name"
```

It works but I would like to make the query part in the results bold.

Example:

```
query = zza
```

results:

- Li**zza**
- Pi**zza**
- Abc**zza**def

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make your own custom filter that alters the input based on the search string :

```
angular.module('app').filter('searchfilter', function() {
    return function (input, query) {
        var r = RegExp('('+ query + ')', 'g');
        return input.replace(r, '<span class="super-class">$1</span>');
    }
});
```

This works, but the filter returns html, so you will need to tell angular to treat the result as html. In order to do this, you need to include [ngSanitize](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular-sanitize.min.js) as a module dependency and insert the result with `ng-bind-html`.
Here's a complete demo :

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <input ng-model="search" placeholder="search a fruit" />
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits| filter:search | limitTo:10" ng-bind-html="fruit | searchfilter:search" ></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the angular part :

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.fruits = 'apple orange banana pineaple grape plumb strawberry lemon lime'.split(' ');
    })
    .filter('searchfilter', function() {
        return function (input, query) {
            return input.replace(RegExp('('+ query + ')', 'g'), '<span class="super-class">$1</span>');           
        }
    });
```

Here's the online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/ZDWdH/2/.

Comment: it's working but in while rendering the list, user image & other details getting hide. I just want to show the all detail of user with the highlighted searched text.

Answer (score 1):

Two hints for the answer from gion_13.

If the query is a empty string (after filtering and then deleting the search term), then the input "apple" is modified like this: 
apple

The solution for this is to change either the regex or a early return:

```
.filter('searchfilter', function() {
    return function (input, query) {
        if (query === '') {
            return input;
        }
        return input.replace(RegExp('('+ query + ')', 'g'), '<span class="super-    class">$1</span>');           
    }    
});
```

If you don't want a case sensitive filter than change the RegExp:

```
RegExp('('+ query + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="super-    class">$1</span>');
```