# AngularJS: Display part of an expression in bold

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My aim is to make part of an angular expression bold.

So basically I'm taking an object `obj`, and converting it to a string `str`.

```
obj = $scope.gridOptions1.api.getFilterModel();
     for (var propt in obj) {
         str += (" " + propt + ': ' + obj[propt]);
     }
```

I then need to find a particular word within that object, for example "Depot".  I'm doing this using `str.indexOf("Depot")`.  I set this to a variable `d`:

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
             var d = str.indexOf("Depot");
}
```

I then replace the ORIGINAL "Depot" with a BOLD "Depot":

```
if (d !== -1 ) {
             var depot = str.substring(d, d + 5);
             finalString = str.replace(depot, depot.bold());
         }
```

Then I fire my string onto the scope:

```
$scope.getFiltered = finalString;
```

the .bold() method is simply returning the string with the bold tags around "Depot" in my UI.

So I'm taking it that the string isn't considered HTML,
is there another way to do this?

Comment: Isn't simpler adding a class to the string where the bold is needed?

Comment: I don't think so in this case, the string may or may not have the word "Depot" in it, it may also may or may not have a few other words I'd like to be bold.  I've basically made a search function to make these word bold no matter where they pop up.  Plus it's an angular expression...

Comment: I don't understand your question... What do you mean by "So I'm taking it that the string isn't considered HTML"

Comment: How do I make PART of an angular expression, so strings passed in between {{ and }} to your HTML, bold........... because the string passed in isn't affected by the bold tags using .bold().  They would be if just using javascript without angular

Comment: you mean something like 
`<div>{{str}}</div>` where `str="some text with Depot"`, this should output 
`<div>some text with <strong>Depot</strong></div>`..?

Comment: You can achieve that by creating a directive where yu can pass the objects of word you want to make bold. That directive will find those word in entire container and will add `<strong></strong>` around it

Comment: @AnandG : that's filters's role...

Comment: Yeah exactly Junius.  I'll look into it Anand G.  I'm trying Vinod's answer first.

Comment: I have answered the way I was saying below. Check out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430172/angularjs-filter-and-bold-part-of-the-result)

> you will need to tell angular to treat the result as html. In order to do this, you need to include ngSanitize as a module dependency and insert the result with ng-bind-html.

So the html will look like

```
 <p ng-bind-html="htmlString"></p>
```

and the angular part

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ng-bind-html to render the string as html content. In your case, use below on the HTML page:

```
<p ng-bind-html="getFiltered"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have tried it this way,

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('wrapInTag', function() {
 return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
          var tag = attr.tag || 'strong';
          var words = eval(attr.words) || [];
          var text = scope.myText;
          
           for(var i=0; i< words.length; i++) {
              text =  text.replace(words[i],'<'+tag+'>'+words[i]+'</'+tag+'>');
            }             
            elm.html(text);
        }
    }
});

 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myText = 'Hello, Here you will find your word in bold';
    $scope.words = ['Hello','your','bold'];
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<bod ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div wrap-in-tag words="{{words}}">{{myText}}! </div>
</div>
  </body>
```

See it working at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyNdbO

Comment: I like this solution very much, I up-voted it but I've to wait for 15 rep for it to go through!  I accepted Denis Bokor's answer because it was a direct answer to my problem.  Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: I am glad that I could help you! It was a learning to me as well so worth more than a upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

What I did to achieve this was to pass my sting and first check if the word I want to change is there, if not I'll just pass the string as it is. Once I know the word is there I just replace the word for the same one in bold.

```
 $scope.makeBold = function(item) {
        if(item.indexOf("LookForMe") != -1)
        {
            b = "LookForMe";
            var d = item.replace(b,b.bold());
            return '<div>'+d+'</div>';
        }
        else {
            return '<div>'+item+'</div>';
        }
    };
```

My controller looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'],function(){});
```

In the HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="makeBold(stringToChange)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$sce` service:

JS:

```
$scope.getFiltered = '<strong>render me as HTML</strong>';
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.getFiltered);
```

HTML:

```
{{trustedHtml}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this with the help of my custom filter.

I can share my approach. Either you can use this code or use the logic.

```
$scope.data = [
                { value: "1", bold: false },
                { value: "2", bold: false },
                { value: "3", bold: false },
                { value: "4", bold: false },
                { value: "5", bold: false },
                { value: "6", bold: false }
            ];
```

this is my data. Actually I want to display and search in 1,2,3,4 etc. For that I have added one more property to each value, `bold`.

And this is my html for the same,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<p ng-repeat="a in data | myFilter : search">
    <b ng-show="a.bold"> {{a.value}} </b>
    <span ng-hide="a.bold">{{a.value}}</span>
</p>
```

And here is my custom filter,

```
app.filter("myFilter", function () {
    return function (input, search) {
        angular.forEach(input, function (value, index) {
            if ( value.value == search) {
                value.bold = true;
            }
            else
            {
                value.bold = false;
            }
        });
        return input;
    };
});
```

Hope this will be really help you.

Happy codding. :)